# Python error: execute() first

Tags: python, mysql, django

When I try to run this view/function, I get the following error `execute() first`.

```
def homepage(request, parem1, parem2):
    # open sql connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if parem1 == 'p':

        if parem2 == 'all':   
            cursor.execute((" SELECT eventname, id, party, DATE_FORMAT(eventdate, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) FROM mainapp_eventdetails ORDER BY eventdate DESC "))
        else:
            cursor.execute((" SELECT eventname, id, party, DATE_FORMAT(eventdate, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) FROM mainapp_eventdetails WHERE party = '" + parem2 + "' ORDER BY eventdate DESC "))

    else:

        if parem2 == 'all':   
            cursor.execute((" SELECT eventname, id, party, DATE_FORMAT(eventdate, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) FROM mainapp_eventdetails ORDER BY eventdate DESC "))
        elif parem2 == 'APR':
            cursor.execute((" SELECT eventname, id, party, DATE_FORMAT(eventdate, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) FROM mainapp_eventdetails WHERE eventdate between '2011-4-1' AND '2011-5-1' ORDER BY eventdate DESC "))

    datalist = [memedetails for memedetails in cursor.fetchall()]

    # close sql connection
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    # group by eventdate
    datalistsorted = []

    # i dont like how this part depends on the sequence of columns retrieved in the above SQL. 
    for k, g in groupby(datalist, key=lambda x:x[3]):
        datalistsorted.append((k,[(i[0],i[1],i[2]) for i in g]))

    return render_to_response('base.html', {'eventlist': datalistsorted, 'parem2': parem2.upper()})
```

But if I were to change this line `elif parem2 == 'APR':` to `else:`, it works fine.

Why is this so and how can I get my `elif` to work? (There are more conditions below but I've omitted it for simplicity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you've hit a case where `parem1` is not 'p' *and* `parem2` is not 'APR'. In this case, you haven't made any calls to execute.

Perhaps you should restrict the if/else to just defining the string to be executed, with a catch-all default, and do the execute call outside the if block.

Comment: You're right, its to do with my parem2 parsing in 'apr' in lower caps hence its not hitting. Thanks. Dumb mistake.

Comment: Is there actually a good reason why it throws an error? You can simply say: *Okay, no query, that's fine, less work for me...* I don't see why this should raise an exception.